# Does Angular ignore css classes inside ng-template?

Tags: css, angular, angular-template

Is there a particular reason why the class inside a dive inside a ng-template doesn't work?
This class works perfectly with any element outside the ng-template but not inside

```
    <div *ngIf='ifTrue; else notAvailable'>{{somethingHere}}</div>
    <ng-template #notAvailable>
        <div class="test">N/A</div>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried on stackblitz, it worked. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-integration-tysbta?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: no it doesn't ignore css classes.